# setting global variable in ipcRenderer.on eventhandler running ionic on electron does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, ipc, render, program-entry-point

This is my code in home.ts to receive values from main-process

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var electron : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  arguments: any="ping";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    electron.ipcRenderer.send("test_channel","ping");
    electron.ipcRenderer.on("test_channel", function (err,arg) {
      this.arguments=arg; // receive new value "pong" from main.js
      console.log("Message received from electron: "+arg); // works fine
    });
    console.log("Message received from electron: "+this.arguments); //does not work, still default value
  };
}
```

This is added in my code in main.js, and it works to receive the event from render-process

```
var ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
ipcMain.on("test_channel",function(err,arg){
  console.log(err);
  console.log("Received message: "+arg);
  global.sharedObj = {prop1: arg};
  console.log("Sending message back!");
  // Send message back!
  mainWindow.webContents.send("test_channel",arg+'yeah');
})
```

This is added in my index.html, to make it run for ionic

```
  <script>
    const electron = require('electron');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't duplicate the message name. and in the main.js , send the event request to the renderer process using event.sender.send as shown below:-

```
ipcMain.on('message_name', (event,args) => {
   event.sender.send('message_name_2', args)
});
```